# Activiti - A Gateway to stop all parallel flows?

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

We are using the [Activiti](http://www.activiti.org/) framework to construct decoupled business processes that will handle specific messages.

BPMN has a notation `Parallel Gateway`, which allows us to create flows of tasks that go in "parallel". But is there a mechanisms (a Gateway) to start **parallel flows** but which will kill other ones as soon as one of the parallel flows finishes?

For example:

```
StartEvent -> ParallelGateway (fork) -> {FlowA, FlowB, FlowC} -> ParallelGateway (join) -> EndEvent
```

If `FlowB` finishes first, the **join Gateway** must NOT wait for other ones to finish, stop them (so that they won't need to be executed to the end) and proceed to the next flow (in the example it's an EndEvent).

Any ideas how to achieve that?

**EDIT**

Found this [thread](http://forums.activiti.org/content/exclusive-join-forked-parallel-gateway-executions) but unfortunately this solution doesn't stop other flows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try to make use of a cancel end event within an embedded transactional subprocess. I never used that feature personally, though. See:

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnCancelEndEvent
http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnBoundaryCancelEvent

What I have in mind is something like:

Outer StartEvent -> Transactional Subprocess Border -> Inner StartEvent -> ParallelGateway (fork) -> {FlowA, FlowB, FlowC} -> XorGateway (join) -> Inner Cancelling EndEvent -> Transactional Subprocess Border with Boundary Cancel Event attached -> Outer EndEvent (with sequence flow coming from Cancel Boundary Event)

The XOR join will cause the first token to arrive at the cancel end event and therefore to cancel the whole transaction. Obviously this is actually a bit of a "misuse" of the construct of "canceling", because the flow will here ALWAYS cancel the transaction, and not just as an "exception to the rule".

(A "terminate end event" instead of the cancelling end event would be a much better fit from a BPMN perspective. Such an end event actually just terminates the subprocess scope the end event is placed inside. In that case the flow could continue without a Boundary Cancel event attached. However, I am unsure whether Activiti at the moment supports this feature, at least I do not find it in the docs...!)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK by definition parallel gateways actually do not model concurrent execution like for e.g., threads running concurrently. Instead the executions are run in order starting with the first one until it reaches a wait state/end or parallel join. The execution engine then begins the other execution in order and so on. So waiting seems to be inherent part of parallel execution

Comment: I know that... that is way I wrote "parallel". :) But the problem is that I don't need the Gateway to wait (or start) other flows. I just need to go one, if one of them is finished (In this case the other ones must be stopped or even not started).

Comment: Although it's not necessary for parallel executions to eventually wait at join gateway (they can end in their own end events by definition) but this is unrelated to your issue. Maybe on a closer look you don't actually need the parallel gateway in the first place.

Comment: The reason of parallel gateways is that different `Call Activity` blocks must be executed. Some of them can wait a lot of time for a response from a different layer. So the problem is that the first sub process that finishes is enough for the whole process to end. But we can't start them in sequence, because they have intermediate `timers` (or tasks that forces the process to wait for a response or a result), which allows running another process while the other one is waiting for a notification.